# Java Android FTP Upload Issue & "Async"

Tags: java, android, ftp

I am attempting to upload via ftp a file, named "advancedsettings.xml" located in path "/storage/emulated/0/advancedsettings.xml" from my Android device. It doesn't seem to be working; the file does not upload and the following exception is thrown:

> 01-06 17:56:17.498  28084-28084/com.name.example.appname E/SmsReceiver﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

**I discovered that basically, an application cannot attempt to perform a networking operation "on its main thread"**.

I am new at Java but I understand, following from this, I must implement "ASync"; I haven't understood how to implement it. Could somebody help describe this to me and how I might implement it in respect of the below code?

My code is as follows:

```
    public class FtpUpload  {

    // use this method to upload the file using file path global var and ftp code,
    //then return the link string.
    //TO DO: UID file name to prevent file already exists overwrite on server?

    public void total() {

        FTPClient con = null;
        String dest_fname = "advancedsettings.xml"; // Added to create a destination file with a dynamically created name (same as the file name in /sdcard/ftp/)

        try
        {
            con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("ftp.domain.co.uk");

            // Check your USERNAME e.g myuser@mywebspace.com and check your PASSWORD to ensure they are OK.
            if (con.login("username", "password"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                String data = "/storage/emulated/0/advancedsettings.xml";

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(data);
                boolean result = con.storeFile(dest_fname, in);
                in.close();
                if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            } else { // This Error Log was created
                // Create error log as a file
                File log_file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/error.txt");

                try {
                    FileWriter lfw = new FileWriter(log_file);
                    BufferedWriter lout = new BufferedWriter(lfw);

                    // Continue
                    lout.write("Upload Connection Failed!");
                    lout.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("SmsReceiver", e1.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", e.toString());
        }


    }
```

Thank you in advance.

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamefully I didn't initially come across [this documentation on Async Tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which has proven invaluable.

With a bit of improv though, I got it working. I just modified my class as such:

```
 private class FtpUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

//code here

}
```

And used the following to call the above Async method:

```
new FtpUpload().execute();
```

Of course, you won't get very far with FTP networking without declaring the following user permissions in your manifest file (outside of the "application" tags):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```